# My intents for my sorted listview won't work properly

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, android-intent

I have a json array and I am using a `for` loop to loop through each object to get the authors name. If the authors name is equal to the authors name that I put in, then that name is added to an arraylist. This array list is then adapted using an array adapter.

But HERE IS MY PROBLEM - I am using this method to search through the json array to find matches.

```
private void updateListView() {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");


        for (int i = 0 ; i <jsonArray.length() ; i++ ) {
            JSONObject post = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stringPost = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
            Log.v(TAG , stringPost);
            if (stringPost.equals("Guil Hernandez")) {
                arrayList.add(stringPost);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG , "no match " + stringPost);
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               arrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

so now that I have my filtered data.... I want to make an intent for each of the results. so I do this

```
 @Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    JSONArray jsonArrayy = null;

    try {
        jsonArrayy = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
        JSONObject jPost = jsonArrayy.getJSONObject(position);
        String url = jPost.getString("url");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

BUT because the data is filtered out.... it opens the wrong url!!! I don't know how to set up my intent so it will get the url for the filtered data... PLEASE HELP. And if this is confusing the full code and JSON data will be listed below and feel free to ask me any questions! Thank you.

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity {

public final static String TAG = MyActivity.class.getSimpleName();



protected JSONObject mBlogData;

private final String KEY_AUTHOR = "author";
private final String KEY_TITLE = "title";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    if (networkIsAvailable()) {
        GetNameData getNameData = new GetNameData();
        getNameData.execute();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    JSONArray jsonArrayy = null;

    try {
        jsonArrayy = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
        JSONObject jPost = jsonArrayy.getJSONObject(position);
        String url = jPost.getString("url");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private boolean networkIsAvailable() {
    boolean isOn = false;
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if ( networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        isOn = true;
    }
    return isOn;
}

private void updateListView() {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");


        for (int i = 0 ; i <jsonArray.length() ; i++ ) {
            JSONObject post = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String stringPost = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
            Log.v(TAG , stringPost);
            if (stringPost.equals("Guil Hernandez")) {
                arrayList.add(stringPost);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG , "no match " + stringPost);
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MyActivity.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
               arrayList);
        setListAdapter(adapter);



    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private class GetNameData extends AsyncTask< Object , Void , JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... objects) {

        int responseCode = -1;

        JSONObject jsonResponse = null;

        try {
            URL bloFeedUrl = new URL("http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/api/get_recent_summary/?count=20");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) bloFeedUrl.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                byte[] array = new byte[8092];
                int read = 0;

                while ((read = inputStream.read(array)) != -1) {
                    builder.append(new String(array, 0, read));
                }

                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonResponse;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
        mBlogData = jsonObject;
        updateListView();
        }
    }
 }
```

JSON

```
{
status: "ok",
count: 20,
count_total: 1949,
pages: 98,
posts: [
{
id: 24680,
url: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-sticky-navigation",
title: "How to Create a Sticky Navigation",
date: "2015-02-05 14:44:13",
author: "Guil Hernandez",
thumbnail: "http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/sticky-150x150.jpg"
},
```

ect......

Answer (score 0):

You can create another list and save the url you want, just what you do with `arrayList`. And then on list item click do this:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

      String url = urlsList.get(position); // your new urls list

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
      startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the order in the listview is not the same in the array you're using, because you are filtering data, so you can keep the url with the post, it will be better if you use objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution i came up with. It is verry sloppy. please tell me if you have a better idea/or a suggestion

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    JSONArray jsonArrayy = null;
    ArrayList<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        jsonArrayy = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < jsonArrayy.length() ; i++) {
            JSONObject post = jsonArrayy.getJSONObject(i);
            String stringPost = post.getString(KEY_AUTHOR);
            String url = post.getString("url");
            Log.v(TAG , stringPost);
            if (stringPost.equals(mName)) {

                urlList.add(url);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG , "no match " + stringPost);
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String urlTwo = urlList.get(position);



    // try {
     //   jsonArrayy = mBlogData.getJSONArray("posts");
       // JSONObject jPost = jsonArrayy.getJSONObject(position);
       // String url = jPost.getString("url");

      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlTwo));
       startActivity(intent);


}
```